# Tier Price Styling bug

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

**Code:**

```
class MinimalTierPriceCalculator extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\MinimalTierPriceCalculator
{

 private $calculator;

 public function __construct(CalculatorInterface $calculator)
{
    $this->calculator = $calculator;
}

public function getAmount(SaleableInterface $saleableItem)
{
    $value = $this->getValue($saleableItem);

    return $value === null
        ? null
        : $this->calculator->getAmount($value, $saleableItem,['weee', 'weee_tax', 'tax']);
}
```

}

i add `$this->calculator->getAmount()` 3rd parameter after adding 3rd parameter tax my price issue fix but styling not good price-including-tax class not adding auto as before.

Comment: what are you trying to achive?

Comment: actually there was issue in tier price i made changes in code after changes html styling change before my change it was bold and inc tax text show there